# Issue with 404 error on page refresh and redirection after deploying Vue.js on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am facing an issue with a 404 error when I refresh the page or try to navigate after deploying my Vue.js application on Netlify. On dev is working fine Below is the routing code I am using:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            component: () => import('../views/Register.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: () => import('../views/Login.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/todo',
            component: () => import('../views/ToDo.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/faq',
            component: () => import('../views/FAQ.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/tickets',
            component: () => import('../views/Tickets.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/new-ticket',
            component: () => import('../views/CreateTicket.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/policy',
            component: () => import('../views/Policy.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/terms',
            component: () => import('../views/Terms.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/chat',
            component: () => import('../views/Chat.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/reset',
            component: () => import('../views/resetPassword.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/resetpassword/',
            component: () => import('../views/resetPassword.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/user',
            component: () => import('../views/CurrentUserPAge.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/user-menu',
            component: () => import('../views/UserMenu.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/set-new-password',
            component: () => import('../views/setNewPassword.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/notification',
            component: () => import('../views/notification.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/admin',
            component: () => import('../views/adminPanel.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/user-edit/:id',
            component: () => import('../views/userEdit.vue')
        }
    ]
});
export default router;
```

I've tried to create routes file, change routes like this:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your app routing is fine, the problem is netlify (like most web servers) wants to serve some HTML page matching the URL path, not knowing that you have a Single Page Application wherein every URL should serve the same file: index.html.  You need to add this redirects file to your project: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps